# Qt , How to make "Pie" custom menu?

Tags: c++, qt, menu

I want to create Pie menu , that popup when user clicking right mouse button , it will have more that one level.

I found a [resource](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq11-piemenu.html) , but I am thinking it is outdated, i searched a lot but cant find any thing useful, one last point i don't want to use *QML*.

so please any thing about this so i can start to implement it , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QtPieMenu was the "official" Qt Widgets component, it was part of the Qt Solutions package that is now discontinued. The last version is 2.4.1. You can't find it in the current Qt project repository, but the code is lying around inside [some projects](https://bitbucket.org/qwerty38/mmgui/src/bd7bc84f89d2?at=default) or in the [code review archive](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/58895/8/qtpiemenu/INSTALL.TXT).

Someone has also made his [own version](http://algoholic.eu/long-lost-qt-goodies-qpiemenu/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer , now i am checking that blog , i think it is useful , thanks again.